# how to delete one directory of a path?

Tags: command-line, delete

Suppose I have a path

```
Leonardo/data/approach/tennis/video
```

and I want to delete `approach` directory, which means that path should look like this:

```
Leonardo/data/tennis/video
```

Can I do it from the terminal with some command?

Without copying `tennis` to `data` and then delete `approach` manually?

Comment: Just move it, instead of copying: `mv Leonardo/data/approach/tennis Leonardo/data/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a simple:

```
mv Leonardo/data/approach/tennis Leonardo/data && rmdir Leonardo/data/approach
```

Why `rmdir`? In order to not delete the directory when subdirectories still exist.

---

*Example*

```
$ mkdir -p Leonardo/data/approach/tennis/video

$ tree                                                                                                                 
.
`-- Leonardo
    `-- data
        `-- approach
            `-- tennis
                `-- video


5 directories, 0 files

$ mv Leonardo/data/approach/tennis Leonardo/data && rmdir Leonardo/data/approach                                    

$  tree                                                                                                                 
.
`-- Leonardo
    `-- data
        `-- tennis
            `-- video

4 directories, 0 files
```

Comment: @kos OMG; I'm stupid

Comment: Nah, It happens to the best of us :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use this function; it will move everything inside the directory passed as an argument one level above, hence taking care of multiple files / folders in the target directory:

```bsh
function delete_dir() {
    [ -d "$1" ] || return;
    for x in "$1"/*; do
        mv -i "$x" "$1"/..
    done
    rmdir "$1"
}
```

Add it at the end of `~/.bashrc` and run `. ~/.bashrc` in the running Bash instances (if any) to apply the changes immediately.

```
$ tree
.
└── foo
    └── bar
        ├── 1
        ├── 2
        └── 3

2 directories, 3 files
$ delete_dir foo/bar
$ tree
.
└── foo
    ├── 1
    ├── 2
    └── 3

1 directory, 3 files
```